# Windows 10 "boot crash"

Tags: windows-10, boot, crash

I have an issue on Windows 10 boot from 2months about. When I power on my pc it seems all ok, it shows the main board logo and starts windows 10. During the boot my pc shut down about 2/3 seconds on the bootlogo (the blue flag of win10). So if I try to power on my pc after that, it starts magically. Do you know how to solve?

Sorry for my English, I'm Italian.

Thanks everybody to try helping me.

Comment: You check the Blue Screen details in event viewer or Use the third party Software to view http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html and check error code first. we get detailed of BSOD

Comment: man I think this is what you asked for    https://imageshack.com/i/poUq2RMbj

Comment: The image you sent shows you had three time blue screen.. one was on April second on may. The third one was june.. which clearly shows you have unsupported driver.. make sure it up to date using driver identifier.. where you can download from same site which will take the drivers from its own official.. you just have select your brand like dell or HP or Lenovo etc.. after that again scan from driver identifier. So it's must be update at last. If it's up to date you won't get last blue screen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below Latest snapshot which you have attached indicates Problem in sptd2.sys driver.

Are You Using Daemon Tools or Alcohol software?.

if Yes remove it completely and cross check before and after the uninstall this software. whether you can see sptd2 file is located in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers` 
After uninstall for those software sptd2 must be removed.

If you really need sptd2 file again to install or re-install you click on this link [SPTD2 for Windows 10](http://www.duplexsecure.com/download/SPTD2inst-v212-x64.exe) download and run it.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I have updated all drivers. Nothing to do

Comment: Did u updated using driver identifier??

Comment: I checked from driver identifier what to update and I have dow the drivers using Google

Comment: After you updated from Google all drivers. did you again run scan for driver using driver identifier again.?? Is it showing up to date

Comment: Yes I have checked. It's all OK but the problem persist

Comment: Still you are getting Blue screen. Its same error. ?? send me the screen of BSOD. latest one

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/2083/kyiQG4.png http://imageshack.com/a/img922/2183/U4HE1w.png The BSOD is changed...

Comment: The snapshot which is shown indicates Problem in sptd2.sys driver. One thing it may be containing virus or file is corrupted. Are You Using Daemon Tools or Alcohol software?. if yes remove it and cross check **before and after** the uninstall this software. whether you can see sptd2 file is located in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers` After uninstall sptd2 must be removed.

Comment: If you really need sptd2 file again to install or re-install you click on this link [SPTD2](http://www.duplexsecure.com/download/SPTD2inst-v212-x64.exe) download and run it.

Comment: FINALLY SOLVED!!! I had daemon tools and alcohol 120%. When I unistalled both, the problem was the same. So I reinstalled SPT2 from the link you posted and now it is OK. Thank you.